# How to translate hardcoded strings in theme's functions.php with wpml string translation?

Tags: string, wordpress, translation, wpml

I added a login/register and a logout menu item to my navigation. Therefore I used following code in my theme's functions.php script:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'footer') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Logout</a></li>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'footer') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('my-account') .'">Login/Register</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

So if the user is logged in the logout menu item will show up, otherwise the login/register menu item. But I have a bilingual website using wpml and would like to know how to make the "Login/Register"-string translatable.

I already tried this:

```
$items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('my-account') .'">'.__('Login/Register').'</a></li>';
```

and also this:

```
$items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('my-account') .'">'.__('Login/Register', 'theme_name').'</a></li>';
```

but it didn't work. According to [this](http://wpml.org/faq/getting-string-translation-to-work/) it should be enough to display the string in the dashboard menu -> wpml -> string translation

So what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

According to one answer of this post: [Why strings don't appear in "String translation" of WPML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889532/why-strings-dont-appear-in-string-translation-of-wpml) I just had to scan the theme again for strings then it showed up!

This line of code I used:

```
$items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('my-account') .'">'.__('Login/Register', 'my_theme_name').'</a></li>';
```